# NSDictionary setValue:forKey: -- getting "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key"

Tags: objective-c, data-structures, nsdictionary

I have this simple loop in my program:

```
for (Element *e in items)
{
    NSDictionary *article = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
    NSLog([[e selectElement: @"title"] contentsText]);
    [article setValue: [[e selectElement: @"title"] contentsText] forKey: @"Title"];

    [self.articles insertObject: article atIndex: [self.articles count]];
    [article release];
}
```

It is using the ElementParser library to make a dictionary of values from an RSS feed (there are other values besides "title" which I have omitted). `self.articles` is an NSMutableArray which is storing all of the dictionaries in the RSS document.

In the end, this should produce an array of dictionaries, with each dictionary containing the information I need about the item at any array index. When I try to use `setValue:forKey:` it gives me the

`this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key "Title"`

error. This has nothing to do with Interface Builder, it is all code-only. Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Any reason why you aren’t using `-setObject:forKey:`, the canonical `NSMutableDictionary` method to add/replace objects in a dictionary?

Comment: When I use that, I get `[__NSDictionary0 setObject:forKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e7efb0'`

Answer (score 92, accepted):

First off, you're using `-setValue:forKey:` on a dictionary when you should be using `-setObject:forKey:`. Secondly, you're trying to mutate an `NSDictionary`, which is an immutable object, instead of an `NSMutableDictionary`, which would work. If you switch to using `-setObject:forKey:` you'll probably get an exception telling you that the dictionary is immutable. Switch your `article` initialization over to

```
NSMutableDictionary *article = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

and it should work.

Comment: Thanks... when I used `NSMutableDictionary` I was using `NSMutableDictionary *article = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];`. Forgot to change the second `NSDictionary`. Derp. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know why in the simulator, it's letting me change the value of the keys of an NSDictionary. But on my device, I'm getting the same error as Logan?

Comment: @prolfe: Where did the dictionary come from? A dictionary returned by `[[NSDictionary alloc] init]` should never let you change its values. A dictionary returned from some other method may actually be an `NSMutableDictionary` under the hood, which means `-setValue:forKey:` would actually succeed. And whatever method returned the dictionary may differ on the simulator vs device. Accidentally attempting to mutate a value typed as `NSDictionary` is one of the reasons why you should prefer `-setObject:forKey:` instead (which will throw a compiler error if you use it on `NSDictionary`).

Answer (score 10):

This:

```
NSDictionary *article = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
```

means that the dictionary is *immutable*. If you want to change its contents, create a mutable dictionary instead:

```
NSMutableDictionary *article = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

Alternatively, you could create your dictionary as:

```
NSDictionary *article = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[[e selectElement: @"title"] contentsText] forKey:@"Title"];
```

and drop the release at the end of that method.

Also, the canonical method to add/replace objects in a (mutable) dictionary is `-setObject:forKey:`. Unless you are familiar with [Key-Value Coding](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html), I suggest you don’t use `-valueForKey:` and `-setValue:forKey:`.