# "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key"

Tags: objective-c, ios

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here but I'm new to obj-c so maybe it's just something I'm not aware of.

I'm getting the exception error at runtime...

> NSDictionaryI 0x9d384d0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not
>   key value coding-compliant for the key overObject.'

On the 4th line of this code...

```
NSDictionary *tempDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];

    Boolean overObjectYES = NO;
    Boolean overObjectNo = NO;

    [tempDictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:overObjectYES] forKey:@"overObject"];
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this is a combination of using `NSDictionary` when you mean `NSMutableDictionary`, and sending the message `setValue` when `setObject` is generally considered more appropriate. See this  question for details:

[NSDictionary setValue:forKey: -- getting "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023829/nsdictionary-setvalueforkey-getting-this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-com)

Comment: Bit confused there, so SetValue, sets the content of the object for the key? and SetObject set's the actual object itself for the key?

Comment: @Phil Ignore the setValue method, it is part of a larger and more complicated topic called Key-Value Coding.  Use setObject instead (which is a method defined by NSMutableDictionary)

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure why there are the two messages - Apple's class reference suggests that `setValue` uses `setObject` but removes the key-value pair if a nil value is passed, whereas `setObject` raises a `NSInvalidArgumentException` [NSMutableDictionary Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: @KendallLister The first one is part of a protocol called NSKeyValueCoding.  Any NSObject can accept it, but some classes (such as NSMutableDictionary) override its behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean `tempDictionary` to be a *mutable* dictionary? If so, declare it as:

```
NSMutableDictionary *tempDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSMutableDictionary`. `NSDictionary` is not editable.

```
NSMutableDictionary *tempDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
Boolean overObjectYES = NO;
Boolean overObjectNo = NO;

[tempDictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:overObjectYES] forKey:@"overObject"];
```